# GAM setting k for spatial autocorrelation across scale

Tags: generalized-additive-model, model-comparison, mgcv, spatio-temporal, basis-function

I am working with a bunch of different GAMs with predictor land cover and remote sensing variables derived at different scales and comparing models within scale. I am not interested in spatial and temporal autocorrelation as an explanatory variable in my model, but it does need to be accounted for (checked with Moran's I). I have done that using:

```
te(long, lat,year, d= c(2,1),  bs = c("ds","tp"))
```

For the models within scale I am setting an upper bound for k of my spatial temporal variable, checking that "null" model and then fixing it for subsequent models that include landscape and remote sensing variables so they can be compared to my null model. At each scale I have a different size data set due to some restriction parameters that reduce the data size at smaller scales.

My question is whether the k values for the spatial and temporal variable should be set across scales or whether it's acceptable to set them by assessing the null model at each scale?

When I set it at each scale I'm worried how much it shifts the other variables (especially at the smallest scale that has the smallest data set). At 30 and 20km when given a flexible k max of (10,5) the null model suggests a spatial temporal edf of 34, ~k of c(7,5), but at 10 km it suggests an edf of ~14 pushing down my k to (5,3)- this makes some of my other predictor variables look very different at this scale than the others. I have a feeling that shifting the year k value across scales is bad and that the lat/lon k may be more flexible, but I can't find anything about this. The lat/long k can go to a minimum of 5, which would give 24 edf- c(5,5). Or is it best to just keep it at c(7,5) like the others?

I am not directly comparing (using AIC) models across scales, but I would like them to be roughly comparable.

Comment: maybe it's worth mentioning my sample size varies between 335 and 800